# How to search for regular expression match on s3 folder, and parse the files

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Below is the s3 folder :

```
s3://bucket-name/20210802-123429/DM/US/2021/08/02/12/test.json
```

20210802-123429 is archive job which puts the files .

what i could achieve:

```
cred_obj = cred_conn.list_objects_v2(Bucket=cfg.Bucket_Details['extractjson'], Prefix="DM"+'/'+"US"+'/'+self.yr+'/'+self.mth+'/'+self.day+'/'+self.hr+'/')
```

Problem statement :

But, in above line, im not sure how to match the criteria for 20210802 and parse the "test.json"

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you actually wanting to achieve? Are you wanting to look through the list of objects in `20210802/*` and find one named `test.json`?

Comment: sorry, missed your post , yes , i need to parse all the JSONs under the 20210802/* and was able to achieve it .

Answer (score 0):

list_objects_v2 does not support RegEx match. The only way to search is using the prefix. Therefore, you must know the prefix or part of the prefix in order to search.

Comment: we know the part of the prefix "20210802" to search, any suggestions how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

```
timestr_arc = todays_dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")

cred_obj = cred_conn.list_objects_v2(Bucket=cfg.Bucket_Details['extractjson'], Prefix="DM"+'/'+"US"+'/'+str(self.timestr_arc))
```

This will check for the specific condition